# Disable scrollbars in bokeh python

Tags: python, bokeh

Hi Stackoverflow gurus!

I have made my bokeh app in python but I have an aesthetic problem. If you scroll with your mouse or using the scrollbars, you move to the vast emptiness.
Do you know how to disable the scrolling in a bokeh app or how to adjust the size of the app area?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior when all of the browser extensions are disabled? If so, can you post the code that exhibits such behavior?

Comment: maybe I misunderstood "vast emptiness".

Answer (score 0):

You can set bounds for the dataranges.  For example:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show


f=figure()
f.x_range.bounds=(0,4)
f.y_range.bounds=(0,10)
f.line(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,4,9])
show(f)
```

See the documentation on [ranges](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html).